# Is this delta epsilon proof ok? (single variable)

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I have to prove that   $$\lim_{x\to0}\; \sqrt {x+3}=\sqrt 3$$

$$ \forall \; \epsilon >0 \;\;\; \exists \; \delta>0:\;0<|x|<\delta \;\rightarrow \; |\sqrt {x+3}-\sqrt {3}|<\epsilon$$
So I started getting rid of the radical in the numerator
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt {x+3}-\sqrt {3}|&=\dfrac{|\sqrt {x+3}-\sqrt {3}|\cdot |\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3}|}{|\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3}|} \\
\\
&=\dfrac{|(\sqrt {x+3}-\sqrt {3})\cdot (\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3})|}{|\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3}|} 
\\
\\
&=\dfrac{|x+3-3|}{|\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3}|}
\\
\\
&=\dfrac{|x|}{|\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt {3}|}
\\
\\
&\leq |x| \quad (\text{I use the fact that the denominator is positive})
\\
\\
&< \delta
\end{align*}
$ \therefore \delta = \epsilon $

Is it ok?

Comment: This proof is fine. The only thing is that the last step is legal since the denominator is larger than $1$ (only being positive wouldn't be enough).

Comment: $$\frac{|x|}{|\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt3|}\leq |x|$$ is not because the denominator is positive, but rather, the denominator is greater than $1$.  Edit:  hello fast fingers

Comment: If you want to be very pedantic you should take $\delta = \min\{\epsilon,3\}$ but I think the proof is fine as-is.

Comment: Knowing the denominator is positive doesn't help: it might be very close to $0$. What's important is that this denominator is bounded from below by a positive number (for instance $1$ – or even $\frac32$).

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion $\delta = \epsilon$ is not okay. You are not writing a proof of $\delta=\epsilon$.

And the last step should be $< \epsilon$ because you want to show that $|\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}| < \epsilon$.

What you mean with writing "$\therefore \delta = \epsilon$" probably is that we can take $\delta=\epsilon$. But then write it in the beginning of the proof.

A recommended structure of a limit proof:

> Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta = \cdots$. Then, whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ we have
>   $$|f(x)-a| = \cdots < \epsilon.$$